# Prove the sequence is infinitesimal and decreasing

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I'd like to prove (if true) the following:

$f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ continuos and decreasing.

$f(x)$ infinitesimal: $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$.

Then the sequence:
$$a_n=\int^{(n+1)\pi}_{n\pi} f(x)|\sin(x)|\,dx$$
is infinitesimal and definitely decreasing.

I tried in different manners, but I'm afraid of missing some theorem to make the proof.
Anyway I'm not really sure the previous fact is true, because it's not an exercise I found in a book.

I'd like some advice or something, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$a_n=\int_0^\pi f(x+n\pi)\sin x\,\mathrm dx $$
hence $$a_n-a_{n+1}=\int_0^\pi(f(x+n\pi)-f(x+(n+1)\pi)\sin x\,\mathrm dx. $$
As we integate ofver a function that is strictly poritive in the interioir of the interval, the integral is positive, hence $(a_n)$ strictly decreasing.
Moreover
$$|a_n|\le \pi\sup_{n\pi\le x\le(n+1)\pi} |f(x)|$$
so that $a_n\to 0$ follows.

Comment: I never did to change the integral in that way, useful to know. But, the last one, I should have get to it. 
Thank you.